# Python - Copy dimension of array in another dimension of the same array (from 2D array to 3D array)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array in the following format

```
(1440, 40)
```

How can I copy the first dimension in the second transforming it in the following 3D array?

```
(1440, 1440, 40)
```

Comment: Could you add an small example of the input and the intended output?

Comment: Have you tried np.repeat?

Comment: This smells like you can use broadcasting in whatever you're try to do with this array, instead of repeating the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to tile a 2d array into a 3d array, you can use the [numpy.tile](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) command:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
>>> print(x.shape)
(2, 3)
>>> print(x)
[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]]
>>> x_3d = np.tile(x, (2, 1, 1))
>>> print(x_3d.shape)
(2, 2, 3)
>>> print(x_3d)
[[[1 2 3]
  [4 5 6]]

 [[1 2 3]
  [4 5 6]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

x is np.array:

```
print(x.shape == (1440, 40)) #True

expected_output = np.repeat(x[:, :, np.newaxis], 40, axis=2)

print(expected_output.shape == (1440, 40, 40)) #True
```

Comment: Mixing lists and arrays like this will very likely be very slow.

Comment: Yes. Corrected list to np.repeat.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new array with the required dimensions, and then copy the data as you like it.

Something like this:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]])
b = np.zeros((a.shape[0], a.shape[0], a.shape[1]))

for i in range(a.shape[0]):
    b[i] = a[i]

print(a.shape) # (2,3)
print(b.shape) # (2,2,3)

######Sample Output########
[[1 2 3]
 [1 2 3]] #a

[[[1. 2. 3.]
  [1. 2. 3.]]
 [[1. 2. 3.]
  [1. 2. 3.]]] #b
```

I am unsure of what you really mean by copying the data. I hope this solves your doubt.